# Extract value of variable from dynamic div with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, html5-video

**I found the answer in another Stack Overflow Q when I did a slightly different search.  The key line of code is this:**

```
var videoFile = $(this).find('.vid_file').text();
```

**with 'this' referencing each videoLink div, then it finds the vid_file div within videoLink, and reads the text.  Hopefully that will help someone else!**

I am creating a dynamic video gallery with HTML, XML and JQuery.  After reading in the XML file, I output an HTML string that creates a dynamic div for each video (.videoLink).  Within that div are child divs that hold the video caption, a path for the background .jpg, and the name of the video file (.vid_file).  All of that is working correctly.  But I am having problems extracting the unique value of each .vid_file (I've got 6 test videos in my dbase).  Here is the code I'm using:

```
$('.videoLink').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('vid_file').each(function (){
    var videoFile = $(this).text();

    var videoCode = '<video controls autoplay autobuffer>' +
        '<source src="video/'+videoFile+'.ogv" type="video/ogg" />' +
        '<source src="video/'+videoFile+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" />' +
        '</video>';

    $('#videoPlayer').html(videoCode);
```

etc. (I'm using fancybox to display the videos -- that is working).  What happens with the above code is that when you click on one, they all play.  I realize that is exactly what i'm asking it to do with this code, but have tried many variations (nesting the click event inside an .each method; vice versa, and more) and getting them to play at all is the closest I've been to making it work. So I think I'm nearly there.  But not quite.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance for your help. -- Cheryl

Comment: can you create jsFiddle for it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the dot in the selector. So use the following.

```
$('.vid_file').each(function (){
    var videoFile = $(this).text();

    var videoCode = '<video controls autoplay autobuffer>' +
        '<source src="video/'+videoFile+'.ogv" type="video/ogg" />' +
        '<source src="video/'+videoFile+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" />' +
        '</video>';

    $('#videoPlayer').html(videoCode);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was a typo.  Have re-done the code too many times!  Still the same -- all six play at once.  Oh, and the one that displays in the lightbox is the last one in the list.